# Not getting readable data from api call

Tags: java, rest, http

I'm trying to call stack exchange's api to get stackoverflow user data that I can parse as a JsonObject, however the data I'm getting back is unreadable garbage.

Here's my code:

```
        String urlName = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?site=stackoverflow";
        URL url = new URL(urlName);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
        InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        conn.disconnect();
```

Am I doing something wrong? I've followed example code and I don't see what I'm doing differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the contents received from `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?site=stackoverflow` are compressed using GZip. Therefore, the unreadable garbage you are seeing is actually the compressed body of the response. Not all contents in a response will be compressed (some sites may choose not to compress them), so you need to check if they are. This can be done using

```
conn.getContentEncoding()
```

Applying this to your code gives you:

```
String urlName = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?site=stackoverflow";
URL url = new URL(urlName);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
}
InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();

if ("gzip".equals(conn.getContentEncoding())) {
    // Is compressed using GZip: Wrap the reader
    inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
}

InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line + "\n");
}
conn.disconnect();
```